# Error trying to run maven on windows

Tags: java, windows, maven, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to get maven set up on windows 7.  I tried version 3.3.3 and 3.3.1 both with the same results.  I have tried changing the jdk using JAVA_HOME and path variables, but I get the same result.
I am new to maven so forgive my ignorance here.

I commented out the echo off from the mvn.cmd script to try and debug.

The java call to start maven just shows the java help message as if the command is invalid somehow. What am I doing wrong?

```
H:\>"C:\bin\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe"    -classpath "c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" "-Dclassworlds.conf=c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\.." "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=H:\" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

---

```
H:\>mvn

H:\>if "H:\" == "" (set "HOME=H:\" )

H:\>if not "" == "" goto skipRcPre

H:\>if exist "H:\\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "H:\\mavenrc_pre.bat"

H:\>if exist "H:\\mavenrc_pre.cmd" call "H:\\mavenrc_pre.cmd"

H:\>set ERROR_CODE=0

H:\>if not "C:\bin\jdk1.7.0_60" == "" goto OkJHome

H:\>if exist "C:\bin\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe" goto chkMHome

H:\>if not "" == "" goto valMHome

H:\>SET "M2_HOME=c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\.."

H:\>if not "c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\.." == "" goto valMHome

H:\>if not "_." == "_\" goto checkMCmd

H:\>if exist "c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..\bin\mvn.cmd" goto init

H:\>set MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=

H:\>set MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=

H:\>IF NOT "" == "" goto endDetectBaseDir

H:\>set EXEC_DIR=H:\

H:\>set WDIR=H:\

H:\>IF EXIST "H:\"\.mvn goto baseDirFound

H:\>cd ..

H:\>IF "H:\" == "H:\" goto baseDirNotFound

H:\>set MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=H:\

H:\>cd "H:\"

H:\>IF NOT EXIST "H:\\.mvn\jvm.config" goto endReadAdditionalConfig

H:\>SET MAVEN_JAVA_EXE="C:\bin\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe"

H:\>for %i in ("c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\.."\boot\plexus-classworlds-*) do set CLASSWORLDS_JAR="%i"

H:\>set CLASSWORLDS_JAR="c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar"

H:\>set CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

H:\>"C:\bin\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe"    -classpath "c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" "-Dclassworlds.conf=c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=c:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\.." "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=H:\" org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

H:\>if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error

H:\>set ERROR_CODE=1

H:\>if not "" == "" goto skipRcPost

H:\>if exist "H:\\mavenrc_post.bat" call "H:\\mavenrc_post.bat"

H:\>if exist "H:\\mavenrc_post.cmd" call "H:\\mavenrc_post.cmd"

H:\>if "" == "on" pause

H:\>if "" == "on" exit 1

H:\>exit /B 1

H:\>
```

Comment: Yes, Clean install.  Just downloaded and unzipped.

Comment: there seems to be a " messing things up ... one of your env vars might be wrong - having a " trailing or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=H:\"` my be the issue. Apparently, java.exe tries to un-escape the string `\"`.

`java "-Dabc=xyz\" my.Dummy`

yields the same error for me, while

`java "-Dabc=xyz\\" my.Dummy` seems to work.

See if things change if you use another project directory path, or try `"-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=H:\\"`.

`%HOME%` is the environment variable mvn looks at, so you may want to set it to another value, or `""` for maven to use the default path of `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

Comment: This helped me figure it out.  HOME, HOMEDRIVE, and HOMEPATH are set by group policy.  I cleared them all and it still didn't work.  But running the command by itself with the additional H:\\ did work.  Turns out changing to a dir outside the root solved the problem. Still can't run in a root folder, but don't really need to.  Thanks!